# Make Top image in UIScrollView enlarge on scroll view bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScroll view with a UIView inside as content view. The layout is:

```
self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

// pin all edges to the edges of the superview (self.view)
self.scrollView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
  make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
}

// create contentView
self.contentView = UIView()
self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.scrollView.addSubview(self.contentView)

// pin the edges of the contentView to the scrollView
self.contentView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
  make.edges.equalTo(self.scrollView) 
}
```

In my contentView I have a UIImageView at the top and some UILabels below:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(...)
let labe1 = UILabel(...)
let labe2 = UILabel(...)
self.contentView.addSubView(imageView)
self.contentView.addSubView(labe1)
self.contentView.addSubView(labe2)
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

When I pull down the scroll view the scroll view bounces at the top. I want that the image enlarges when the scroll view bounces.

I did this with the `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if offsetY < -64 {
      let progress:CGFloat = fabs(offsetY + 64) / 100
      self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1 + progress, 1 + progress)
    }
  }
```

This works but the problem is that when the image is transformed it should not overlay the border to the red area which contains the Labels. Here is what happens when I bounce:

[image]

I want that the image still enlarges but not overlapping the border to the red area. How can I do that?

Comment: Just set the imageViews clipsToBounds property to true.

Comment: No it is not that simple because when you do that the image will not scale to the top of the screen. That is what I want!

Comment: In this case you should also modify the height of the image with the amount of scrolling, but clipToBounds has to be true.

Comment: As I said I cannot use clipToBounds!

Comment: No, you can, think about it: when you scroll down, do imageViews origin (the top of the image view) is goes down as well, and if you use clipToBounds, those parts that are above the top of the image view are gone. But if you increase the height of the image view (and possible move its origin upper with the same amount as the height increase), then the effect will be the same as you want.

Comment: This is to abstract. Could you please post an answer with an example. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to resize the whole `UIScrollView` with pager view - don't forget to reset its's frame back to prevent wrong paging.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty UIView with some background color as highlighted in image
[image]

Or in your code

```
let imageView = UIImageView(...)
let labe1 = UILabel(...)
let labe2 = UILabel(...)
self.contentView.addSubView(imageView)
//add one more UIView with some background color here
self.contentView.addSubView(labe1)
self.contentView.addSubView(labe2)
```